# C Convert CFNumber(kCFNumberSInt64Type) to a long or int

Tags: objective-c

(Have updated the question with code)
As the title says I was wondering if it possible to convert a `CFNumber(kCFNumberSInt64Type)` to a long or int ? 
Here is the code that im currently using.

```
    #include "MobileDevice.h"

void device_callback(struct am_device_notification_callback_info *info, void *arg) {
    struct am_device *dev;
    if (info->msg == ADNCI_MSG_CONNECTED) {
        dev = info->dev;
        CFRetain(dev);
        AMDSetLogLevel(5);
        AMDeviceConnect(dev);
        assert(AMDeviceIsPaired(dev));
        assert(!AMDeviceValidatePairing(dev));
        assert(!AMDeviceStartSession(dev));

        assert(AMDeviceIsPaired(dev));
        assert(AMDeviceValidatePairing(dev) == 0);

        int64_t i1, i2 = 42;
        CFNumberRef ecid = AMDeviceCopyValue(dev, 0, CFSTR("UniqueChipID")); // this is what I want as a long/int

        printf("ecid  (%s)",CFNumberGetValue(ecid, kCFNumberSInt64Type, &i1));

    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct am_device_notification *notify;
    AMDeviceNotificationSubscribe(&device_callback, 0, 0, NULL, &notify);
    CFRunLoopRun();

}

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *   MobileDevice.h - interface to MobileDevice.framework
 *   $LastChangedDate: 2007-07-09 18:59:29 -0700 (Mon, 09 Jul 2007) $
 *
 * Copied from http://iphonesvn.halifrag.com/svn/iPhone/
 * With modifications from Allen Porter and Scott Turner
 *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#ifndef MOBILEDEVICE_H
#define MOBILEDEVICE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#if defined(WIN32)
#include <CoreFoundation.h>
    typedef unsigned int mach_error_t;
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <mach/error.h>
#endif

    /* Error codes */
#define MDERR_APPLE_MOBILE  (err_system(0x3a))
#define MDERR_IPHONE        (err_sub(0))

    /* Apple Mobile (AM*) errors */
#define MDERR_OK                ERR_SUCCESS
#define MDERR_SYSCALL           (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x01)
#define MDERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY     (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x03)
#define MDERR_QUERY_FAILED      (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x04)
#define MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x0b)
#define MDERR_DICT_NOT_LOADED   (ERR_MOBILE_DEVICE | 0x25)

    /* Apple File Connection (AFC*) errors */
#define MDERR_AFC_OUT_OF_MEMORY 0x03

    /* USBMux errors */
#define MDERR_USBMUX_ARG_NULL   0x16
#define MDERR_USBMUX_FAILED     0xffffffff

    /* Messages passed to device notification callbacks: passed as part of
     * am_device_notification_callback_info. */
#define ADNCI_MSG_CONNECTED     1
#define ADNCI_MSG_DISCONNECTED  2
#define ADNCI_MSG_UNKNOWN       3

#define AMD_IPHONE_PRODUCT_ID   0x1290
#define AMD_IPHONE_SERIAL       "3391002d9c804d105e2c8c7d94fc35b6f3d214a3"

    /* Services, found in /System/Library/Lockdown/Services.plist */
#define AMSVC_AFC                   CFSTR("com.apple.afc")
#define AMSVC_BACKUP                CFSTR("com.apple.mobilebackup")
#define AMSVC_CRASH_REPORT_COPY     CFSTR("com.apple.crashreportcopy")
#define AMSVC_DEBUG_IMAGE_MOUNT     CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.debug_image_mount")
#define AMSVC_NOTIFICATION_PROXY    CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.notification_proxy")
#define AMSVC_PURPLE_TEST           CFSTR("com.apple.purpletestr")
#define AMSVC_SOFTWARE_UPDATE       CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.software_update")
#define AMSVC_SYNC                  CFSTR("com.apple.mobilesync")
#define AMSVC_SCREENSHOT            CFSTR("com.apple.screenshotr")
#define AMSVC_SYSLOG_RELAY          CFSTR("com.apple.syslog_relay")
#define AMSVC_SYSTEM_PROFILER       CFSTR("com.apple.mobile.system_profiler")

    typedef unsigned int afc_error_t;
    typedef unsigned int usbmux_error_t;
    typedef unsigned int service_conn_t;

    struct am_recovery_device;

    typedef struct am_device_notification_callback_info {
        struct am_device *dev;  /* 0    device */
        unsigned int msg;       /* 4    one of ADNCI_MSG_* */
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) am_device_notification_callback_info;

    /* The type of the device restore notification callback functions.
     * TODO: change to correct type. */
    typedef void (*am_restore_device_notification_callback)(struct
    am_recovery_device *);

    /* This is a CoreFoundation object of class AMRecoveryModeDevice. */
    typedef struct am_recovery_device {
        unsigned char unknown0[8];                          /* 0 */
        am_restore_device_notification_callback callback;   /* 8 */
        void *user_info;                                    /* 12 */
        unsigned char unknown1[12];                         /* 16 */
        unsigned int readwrite_pipe;                        /* 28 */
        unsigned char read_pipe;                            /* 32 */
        unsigned char write_ctrl_pipe;                      /* 33 */
        unsigned char read_unknown_pipe;                    /* 34 */
        unsigned char write_file_pipe;                      /* 35 */
        unsigned char write_input_pipe;                     /* 36 */
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) am_recovery_device;

    /* A CoreFoundation object of class AMRestoreModeDevice. */
    typedef struct am_restore_device {
        unsigned char unknown[32];
        int port;
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) am_restore_device;

    /* The type of the device notification callback function. */
    typedef void(*am_device_notification_callback)(struct
    am_device_notification_callback_info *, void* arg);

    /* The type of the _AMDDeviceAttached function.
     * TODO: change to correct type. */
    typedef void *amd_device_attached_callback;


    typedef struct am_device {
        unsigned char unknown0[16]; /* 0 - zero */
        unsigned int device_id;     /* 16 */
        unsigned int product_id;    /* 20 - set to AMD_IPHONE_PRODUCT_ID */
        char *serial;               /* 24 - set to AMD_IPHONE_SERIAL */
        unsigned int unknown1;      /* 28 */
        unsigned char unknown2[4];  /* 32 */
        unsigned int lockdown_conn; /* 36 */
        unsigned char unknown3[8];  /* 40 */
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) am_device;

    typedef struct am_device_notification {
        unsigned int unknown0;                      /* 0 */
        unsigned int unknown1;                      /* 4 */
        unsigned int unknown2;                      /* 8 */
        am_device_notification_callback callback;   /* 12 */
        unsigned int unknown3;                      /* 16 */
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) am_device_notification;

    typedef struct afc_connection {
        unsigned int handle;            /* 0 */
        unsigned int unknown0;          /* 4 */
        unsigned char unknown1;         /* 8 */
        unsigned char padding[3];       /* 9 */
        unsigned int unknown2;          /* 12 */
        unsigned int unknown3;          /* 16 */
        unsigned int unknown4;          /* 20 */
        unsigned int fs_block_size;     /* 24 */
        unsigned int sock_block_size;   /* 28: always 0x3c */
        unsigned int io_timeout;        /* 32: from AFCConnectionOpen, usu. 0 */
        void *afc_lock;                 /* 36 */
        unsigned int context;           /* 40 */
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) afc_connection;

    typedef struct afc_directory {
        unsigned char unknown[0];   /* size unknown */
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) afc_directory;

    typedef struct afc_dictionary {
        unsigned char unknown[0];   /* size unknown */
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) afc_dictionary;

    typedef unsigned long long afc_file_ref;

    typedef struct usbmux_listener_1 {                  /* offset   value in iTunes */
        unsigned int unknown0;                  /* 0        1 */
        unsigned char *unknown1;                /* 4        ptr, maybe device? */
        amd_device_attached_callback callback;  /* 8        _AMDDeviceAttached */
        unsigned int unknown3;                  /* 12 */
        unsigned int unknown4;                  /* 16 */
        unsigned int unknown5;                  /* 20 */
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) usbmux_listener_1;

    typedef struct usbmux_listener_2 {
        unsigned char unknown0[4144];
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) usbmux_listener_2;

    typedef struct am_bootloader_control_packet {
        unsigned char opcode;       /* 0 */
        unsigned char length;       /* 1 */
        unsigned char magic[2];     /* 2: 0x34, 0x12 */
        unsigned char payload[0];   /* 4 */
    } __attribute__ ((packed)) am_bootloader_control_packet;

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *   Public routines
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    void AMDSetLogLevel(int level);

    /*  Registers a notification with the current run loop. The callback gets
     *  copied into the notification struct, as well as being registered with the
     *  current run loop. dn_unknown3 gets copied into unknown3 in the same.
     *  (Maybe dn_unknown3 is a user info parameter that gets passed as an arg to
     *  the callback?) unused0 and unused1 are both 0 when iTunes calls this.
     *  In iTunes the callback is located from $3db78e-$3dbbaf.
     *
     *  Returns:
     *      MDERR_OK            if successful
     *      MDERR_SYSCALL       if CFRunLoopAddSource() failed
     *      MDERR_OUT_OF_MEMORY if we ran out of memory
     */

    mach_error_t AMDeviceNotificationSubscribe(am_device_notification_callback
                                               callback, unsigned int unused0, unsigned int unused1, void* //unsigned int
                                               dn_unknown3, struct am_device_notification **notification);

    /*  Connects to the iPhone. Pass in the am_device structure that the
     *  notification callback will give to you.
     *
     *  Returns:
     *      MDERR_OK                if successfully connected
     *      MDERR_SYSCALL           if setsockopt() failed
     *      MDERR_QUERY_FAILED      if the daemon query failed
     *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if USBMuxConnectByPort returned 0xffffffff
     */

    mach_error_t AMDeviceConnect(struct am_device *device);

    /*  Calls PairingRecordPath() on the given device, than tests whether the path
     *  which that function returns exists. During the initial connect, the path
     *  returned by that function is '/', and so this returns 1.
     *
     *  Returns:
     *      0   if the path did not exist
     *      1   if it did
     */

    int AMDeviceIsPaired(struct am_device *device);

    /*  iTunes calls this function immediately after testing whether the device is
     *  paired. It creates a pairing file and establishes a Lockdown connection.
     *
     *  Returns:
     *      MDERR_OK                if successful
     *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the supplied device is null
     *      MDERR_DICT_NOT_LOADED   if the load_dict() call failed
     */

    mach_error_t AMDeviceValidatePairing(struct am_device *device);

    /*  Creates a Lockdown session and adjusts the device structure appropriately
     *  to indicate that the session has been started. iTunes calls this function
     *  after validating pairing.
     *
     *  Returns:
     *      MDERR_OK                if successful
     *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the Lockdown conn has not been established
     *      MDERR_DICT_NOT_LOADED   if the load_dict() call failed
     */

    mach_error_t AMDeviceStartSession(struct am_device *device);

    /* Starts a service and returns a handle that can be used in order to further
     * access the service. You should stop the session and disconnect before using
     * the service. iTunes calls this function after starting a session. It starts
     * the service and the SSL connection. unknown may safely be
     * NULL (it is when iTunes calls this), but if it is not, then it will be
     * filled upon function exit. service_name should be one of the AMSVC_*
     * constants. If the service is AFC (AMSVC_AFC), then the handle is the handle
     * that will be used for further AFC* calls.
     *
     * Returns:
     *      MDERR_OK                if successful
     *      MDERR_SYSCALL           if the setsockopt() call failed
     *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the Lockdown conn has not been established
     */

    mach_error_t AMDeviceStartService(struct am_device *device, CFStringRef
                                      service_name, service_conn_t *handle, unsigned int *
                                      unknown);

    mach_error_t AMDeviceStartHouseArrestService(struct am_device *device, CFStringRef identifier, void *unknown, service_conn_t *handle, unsigned int *what);

    /* Stops a session. You should do this before accessing services.
     *
     * Returns:
     *      MDERR_OK                if successful
     *      MDERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT  if the Lockdown conn has not been established
     */

    mach_error_t AMDeviceStopSession(struct am_device *device);

    /* Opens an Apple File Connection. You must start the appropriate service
     * first with AMDeviceStartService(). In iTunes, io_timeout is 0.
     *
     * Returns:
     *      MDERR_OK                if successful
     *      MDERR_AFC_OUT_OF_MEMORY if malloc() failed
     */

    afc_error_t AFCConnectionOpen(service_conn_t handle, unsigned int io_timeout,
                                  struct afc_connection **conn);

    /* Pass in a pointer to an afc_device_info structure. It will be filled. */
    afc_error_t AFCDeviceInfoOpen(afc_connection *conn, struct
                                  afc_dictionary **info);

    /* Turns debug mode on if the environment variable AFCDEBUG is set to a numeric
     * value, or if the file '/AFCDEBUG' is present and contains a value. */
    void AFCPlatformInit();

    /* Opens a directory on the iPhone. Pass in a pointer in dir to be filled in.
     * Note that this normally only accesses the iTunes sandbox/partition as the
     * root, which is /var/root/Media. Pathnames are specified with '/' delimiters
     * as in Unix style.
     *
     * Returns:
     *      MDERR_OK                if successful
     */

    afc_error_t AFCDirectoryOpen(afc_connection *conn, const char *path,
                                 struct afc_directory **dir);

    /* Acquires the next entry in a directory previously opened with
     * AFCDirectoryOpen(). When dirent is filled with a NULL value, then the end
     * of the directory has been reached. '.' and '..' will be returned as the
     * first two entries in each directory except the root; you may want to skip
     * over them.
     *
     * Returns:
     *      MDERR_OK                if successful, even if no entries remain
     */

    afc_error_t AFCDirectoryRead(afc_connection *conn/*unsigned int unused*/, struct afc_directory *dir,
                                 char **dirent);

    afc_error_t AFCDirectoryClose(afc_connection *conn, struct afc_directory *dir);
    afc_error_t AFCDirectoryCreate(afc_connection *conn, const char *dirname);
    afc_error_t AFCRemovePath(afc_connection *conn, const char *dirname);
    afc_error_t AFCRenamePath(afc_connection *conn, const char *from, const char *to);
    afc_error_t AFCLinkPath(afc_connection *conn, long long int linktype, const char *target, const char *linkname);

    /* Returns the context field of the given AFC connection. */
    unsigned int AFCConnectionGetContext(afc_connection *conn);

    /* Returns the fs_block_size field of the given AFC connection. */
    unsigned int AFCConnectionGetFSBlockSize(afc_connection *conn);

    /* Returns the io_timeout field of the given AFC connection. In iTunes this is
     * 0. */
    unsigned int AFCConnectionGetIOTimeout(afc_connection *conn);

    /* Returns the sock_block_size field of the given AFC connection. */
    unsigned int AFCConnectionGetSocketBlockSize(afc_connection *conn);

    /* Closes the given AFC connection. */
    afc_error_t AFCConnectionClose(afc_connection *conn);

    /* Registers for device notifications related to the restore process. unknown0
     * is zero when iTunes calls this. In iTunes,
     * the callbacks are located at:
     *      1: $3ac68e-$3ac6b1, calls $3ac542(unknown1, arg, 0)
     *      2: $3ac66a-$3ac68d, calls $3ac542(unknown1, 0, arg)
     *      3: $3ac762-$3ac785, calls $3ac6b2(unknown1, arg, 0)
     *      4: $3ac73e-$3ac761, calls $3ac6b2(unknown1, 0, arg)
     */

    unsigned int AMRestoreRegisterForDeviceNotifications(
                                                         am_restore_device_notification_callback dfu_connect_callback,
                                                         am_restore_device_notification_callback recovery_connect_callback,
                                                         am_restore_device_notification_callback dfu_disconnect_callback,
                                                         am_restore_device_notification_callback recovery_disconnect_callback,
                                                         unsigned int unknown0,
                                                         void *user_info);

    /* Causes the restore functions to spit out (unhelpful) progress messages to
     * the file specified by the given path. iTunes always calls this right before
     * restoring with a path of
     * "$HOME/Library/Logs/iPhone Updater Logs/iPhoneUpdater X.log", where X is an
     * unused number.
     */

    unsigned int AMRestoreEnableFileLogging(char *path);

    /* Initializes a new option dictionary to default values. Pass the constant
     * kCFAllocatorDefault as the allocator. The option dictionary looks as
     * follows:
     * {
     *      NORImageType => 'production',
     *      AutoBootDelay => 0,
     *      KernelCacheType => 'Release',
     *      UpdateBaseband => true,
     *      DFUFileType => 'RELEASE',
     *      SystemImageType => 'User',
     *      CreateFilesystemPartitions => true,
     *      FlashNOR => true,
     *      RestoreBootArgs => 'rd=md0 nand-enable-reformat=1 -progress'
     *      BootImageType => 'User'
     *  }
     *
     * Returns:
     *      the option dictionary   if successful
     *      NULL                    if out of memory
     */

    CFMutableDictionaryRef AMRestoreCreateDefaultOptions(CFAllocatorRef allocator);

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *   Less-documented public routines
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    /* mode 2 = read, mode 3 = write */
    afc_error_t AFCFileRefOpen(afc_connection *conn, const char *path,
                               unsigned long long mode, afc_file_ref *ref);
    afc_error_t AFCFileRefSeek(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
                               unsigned long long offset1, unsigned long long offset2);
    afc_error_t AFCFileRefRead(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
                               void *buf, unsigned int *len);
    afc_error_t AFCFileRefSetFileSize(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
                                      unsigned long long offset);
    afc_error_t AFCFileRefWrite(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref,
                                const void *buf, unsigned int len);
    afc_error_t AFCFileRefClose(afc_connection *conn, afc_file_ref ref);

    afc_error_t AFCFileInfoOpen(afc_connection *conn, const char *path, struct
                                afc_dictionary **info);
    afc_error_t AFCKeyValueRead(struct afc_dictionary *dict, char **key, char **
                                val);
    afc_error_t AFCKeyValueClose(struct afc_dictionary *dict);

    unsigned int AMRestorePerformRecoveryModeRestore(struct am_recovery_device *
                                                     rdev, CFDictionaryRef opts, void *callback, void *user_info);
    unsigned int AMRestorePerformRestoreModeRestore(struct am_restore_device *
                                                    rdev, CFDictionaryRef opts, void *callback, void *user_info);

    struct am_restore_device *AMRestoreModeDeviceCreate(unsigned int unknown0,
                                                        unsigned int connection_id, unsigned int unknown1);

    unsigned int AMRestoreCreatePathsForBundle(CFStringRef restore_bundle_path,
                                               CFStringRef kernel_cache_type, CFStringRef boot_image_type, unsigned int
                                               unknown0, CFStringRef *firmware_dir_path, CFStringRef *
                                               kernelcache_restore_path, unsigned int unknown1, CFStringRef *
                                               ramdisk_path);

    unsigned int AMDeviceGetConnectionID(struct am_device *device);
    mach_error_t AMDeviceEnterRecovery(struct am_device *device);
    mach_error_t AMDeviceDisconnect(struct am_device *device);
    mach_error_t AMDeviceRetain(struct am_device *device);
    mach_error_t AMDeviceRelease(struct am_device *device);
    CFStringRef AMDeviceCopyValue(struct am_device *device, unsigned int, CFStringRef cfstring);
    CFStringRef AMDeviceCopyDeviceIdentifier(struct am_device *device);

    typedef void (*notify_callback)(CFStringRef notification, void *data);

    mach_error_t AMDPostNotification(service_conn_t socket, CFStringRef  notification, CFStringRef userinfo);
    mach_error_t AMDObserveNotification(void *socket, CFStringRef notification);
    mach_error_t AMDListenForNotifications(void *socket, notify_callback cb, void *data);
    mach_error_t AMDShutdownNotificationProxy(void *socket);

    /*edits by geohot*/
    mach_error_t AMDeviceDeactivate(struct am_device *device);
    mach_error_t AMDeviceActivate(struct am_device *device, CFMutableDictionaryRef);
    /*end*/

    void *AMDeviceSerialize(struct am_device *device);
    void AMDAddLogFileDescriptor(int fd);
    //kern_return_t AMDeviceSendMessage(service_conn_t socket, void *unused, CFPropertyListRef plist);
    //kern_return_t AMDeviceReceiveMessage(service_conn_t socket, CFDictionaryRef options, CFPropertyListRef * result);

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *   Semi-private routines
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    /*  Pass in a usbmux_listener_1 structure and a usbmux_listener_2 structure
     *  pointer, which will be filled with the resulting usbmux_listener_2.
     *
     *  Returns:
     *      MDERR_OK                if completed successfully
     *      MDERR_USBMUX_ARG_NULL   if one of the arguments was NULL
     *      MDERR_USBMUX_FAILED     if the listener was not created successfully
     */

    usbmux_error_t USBMuxListenerCreate(struct usbmux_listener_1 *esi_fp8, struct
                                        usbmux_listener_2 **eax_fp12);

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *   Less-documented semi-private routines
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    usbmux_error_t USBMuxListenerHandleData(void *);

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
     *   Private routines - here be dragons
     * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

    /* AMRestorePerformRestoreModeRestore() calls this function with a dictionary
     * in order to perform certain special restore operations
     * (RESTORED_OPERATION_*). It is thought that this function might enable
     * significant access to the phone. */

    typedef unsigned int (*t_performOperation)(struct am_restore_device *rdev,
    CFDictionaryRef op); // __attribute__ ((regparm(2)));

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Would love if someone knows a solution to the problem I have :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715991/how-to-extract-64-bit-signed-integer-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you posted way too much irrelevant code. When you post code to ask about, you should reduce it to a minimal example that still reproduces the problem.

You should also explain precisely what the problem is. Is there a compile error? Do you get a wrong value?

Anyway, I assume the problem is with this line:

```
    printf("ecid  (%s)",CFNumberGetValue(ecid, kCFNumberSInt64Type, &i1));
```

That's because the return value from `CFNumberGetValue()` is not the value which was retrieved. It is a boolean value indicating success or failure. The value that was retrieved is stored in the variable whose address was passed in the third parameter. You passed the address of `i1`, so it is stored in that variable.

Also, you have used the `%s` format specifier, which requires a pointer to a C-style string (null-terminated array of characters). You won't get sensible results if you pass an integer or a boolean. You'll likely get a crash.

You could do something like:

```
if (CFNumberGetValue(ecid, kCFNumberSInt64Type, &i1))
    printf("ecid  (%lld)", i1);
else
    /* handle failure */;
```

Another approach, since you're using Objective-C, is to take advantage of the fact that `CFNumber` is toll-free bridged to `NSNumber`:

```
    NSNumber* ecid = (NSNumber*)CFBridgingRelease(AMDeviceCopyValue(dev, 0, CFSTR("UniqueChipID"))); // this is what I want as a long/int

    printf("ecid  (%lld)", ecid.longLongValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [CFNumberGetValue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFNumberRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/CFNumberGetValue).

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
int64_t i1, i2 = 42;
CFNumberRef cfnum = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberSInt64Type, &i2);
/* We now got a CFNumberRef which encapsulates i2's value */
CFNumberGetValue(cfnum, kCFNumberSInt64Type, &i1);
/* We now got the same value in i1 */
```

I am not too well versed with Objective C, but I think C99 support (and the optional `<stdint.h>`) should be guaranteed.

Comment: I did´t seem to get it to work.... :( but I  have updated the question with some code, so hope you can see what I´m doing wrong :-)